# Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android

i have this error:
Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
Failed to allocate a 8640012 byte allocation with 6781976 free bytes and 6MB until OOM
com.olgazelenko.esofer.AlegeTestulB.onCreate

I tried to fix it by adding:   android:largeHeap="true" but i still got the error.

there is the stacktrace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 8640012 byte allocation with 6781976 free bytes and 6MB until OOM
   at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(VMRuntime.java)
   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(BitmapFactory.java)
   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:655)
   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:483)
   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1157)
   at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:720)
   at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:571)
   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:972)
   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:935)
   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4232)
   at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:733)
   at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:109)
   at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:105)
   at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:71)
   at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:67)
   at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createButton(AppCompatViewInflater.java:187)
   at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:110)
   at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1266)
   at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1316)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:769)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
   at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
   at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
   at com.olgazelenko.esofer.AlegeTestulB.onCreate(AlegeTestulB.java:52)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6666)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2677)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2789)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1527)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
```

does someone know how that can be fixed? thanks in advance

Comment: Post the used code.

Comment: are you trying to load a big image? it could be that it is too large to load to memory

Comment: check it out: https://justpaste.it/5i65q

Comment: @rexxar i compressed the image.. i thinked it was the same thing, the image being too large. what should i do?

Comment: this should make your code more readable... https://pastebin.com/UVYckfdn

Comment: are you sure you don't have any images or files larger than 6MB in your project?

Comment: you should check AlegeTestulB.java file and its corresponding XML layout for any drawables

Comment: i did it right now... all images are below 100kb.

Comment: is there a lot of images on the screen at once? could you post XML for AlegeTestB Activity? I can't tell without seeing the full project, but if you're trying to load too many images at once, that can fill up memory real fast

Comment: yes, i am trying to load a lot of images at once. and you are right, it is filling up the ram so fast i think. there is the XML: https://pastebin.com/5AUKpCnn

Comment: You glide or picasso for loading a lot of images in android. These libraries also have parameters for decreasing the quality or size of images.

Comment: I will post my conclusion as an answer

Comment: :)) so what should i do next?:D @no_fate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is based on the layout found in your XML: https://pastebin.com/5AUKpCnn

```
 <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    ...
    <Button...
    <Button...
    <Button...
    ...
 </ScrollView>
```

It seems that you're trying to create a List by using a ScrollView and a lot of Buttons.
Creating a list like that loads all your images at once.

You should check out Android's ListView or RecyclerView for creating a list of clickable images. Those two can make things easier for you with their handling of List items so that they're not loaded all at the same time.

Comment: i am working on it rn, i will accept it when i see if that works, thanks in advance mate!